# How to Inform Google For Page URL Modifications in Same Domain?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console

I am renewing my web page and changing the site structure. It was in Asp and now it will be in Asp.Net

So page URLs will be modified. And some pages will be removed, some will be added. But mostly, the content and page names are same, only URLs will change.

The site has SEO work in it and we want to loose it minimum.Site is registered in Analytics and Webmaster Tools.

Google searches will end up blank pages and I don't want to loose my rank.

So I'm looking for a way to inform Google about new page URLs. Domain is same, only URLs. For example: the home page was `/default.asp` and now `/home.aspx`

Is there a way to tell Google that a particular URL address or page name has changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement some form of 301 (301 is key) redirects. This way when google or any other search hits the old page, the index is refreshed with the new page. Asp.net allows you to do these redirects even at the IIS level, and where I'd suggest that they live.  You'll also want to submit an up to date site map on webmaster tools.

Edit: Here's a good link on the redirects, http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpRedirect

Comment: thanks, clear enough but what about urls? will the url in google search results change? I saw a post here tells only way is to upload a sitemap, you agree with that or 301 does it too?

Comment: The links in the results are updated too. I would suggest both sitemap changes and the redirects. But I would put the priority on the redirects.

Answer (score 1):

If all that is changing are the page URLs, Google Analytics cannot "know" that a page is the same, just with diferent URL.

But, you could apply a customized pageview using the _trackPageView() method, giving it the original url as parameter.

If you choose to do this, you will have to exclude the line that uses the method in the original GA code and apply it elsewhere, or pass the parameter to it directly with the orignial URL. All this is done in each page.

You can also read more about the method [here](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55597).

Comment: +1 for help and the link, I think I'll go with the 301 redirect and providing a sitemap but that's a good information.

Answer (score 1):

For IIS (Asp.Net) you want to look into the following to find out how to do 301 redirects:

Response.RedirectPermanent(...) for redirecting from a page
or
"IIS 7 Routing Module and web.config" to set up bulk redirecting

I'd also suggest you consider supporting Search Engine Friendly (SEF) URLs while your making the move. The Routing Module can help you there as well.

Comment: thanks for the tip. since my old files were asp and html, I chose another way. but your way will guide me when it's about asp.net.

Comment: The routing option can do asp to aspx files as well. In fact any file if it's configured.